# Can emails be filtered by GMail (or something else) for an IMAP account into a folder?

Tags: gmail, email, filter

I have an IMAP email account that receives daily emails from a cron process on a regular basis. I currently use GMail to read this account from my Android device. Is there a way for the GMail application to automatically filter emails to place them in an IMAP folder so I do not receive notifications for this every time a cron email arrives in the inbox?

I have Thunderbird setup on my laptop to automatically move the emails from the cron job to a folder. I would like to do something similar to my Android mail client.

I am interested in solutions for Android 4.4, Android 5, and Android 7.